# Editing IP through xfce4 desktop

Tags: networking, 18.04, xfce

Alright, so I am new to using the server version of ubuntu and even newer to the /etc/netplan. I have tried creating a .yaml file but always seam to make mistakes with the syntax, I have xfce4 installed on my 18.04.1 server and it comes up with the Ethernet symbol in the top right corner but when I go into it I can not edit the current adaptor and when I try to create a new one all the options are greyed out and inaccessible. So does anyone know how I can set my ip to 192.168.0.2 so my modems firewall entries don't need to be changed?

Comment: Is Network Manager installed and running? Confirm: `ps aux | grep -i network`

Comment: I believe it is running yes, I am pretty sure installing it was one step I tried when trying to get a gui up because I was having trouble with yaml syntax.
The dropbox link leads to two snips one of the output of the command you asked for the other is what I see on xfce when using tight VNC.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k3sykzksl0r9rz8/AAAb0A07VjOIx87B0QNB60SFa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix the problem, but I did have to reinstall, last time during set up I was unable to configure a static IP as it would tell me that the IP was not contained in the subnetmask 255.255.255.0/24, which is the subnet mask used by all my other devices as far as I know. I had to instead use 192.168.0.0/24 and it finally let me set a static IP. That being said anyone who can tell me how I can change such setting from within the xfce gui would be appreciated greatly.